Character Combining 山 and 大
I am currently reading official documents from the early twentieth century and there is one character which occurs frequently but for which I have so far not been able to find a translation. It is basically a combination of 山 and 大, 山 being the raidal on the left and 大 being on the right-hand side.
Any advice is appreciated!
Thanks in advance!
Tim


This is a variant of 此 cǐ "this, here". This variant, although resembling ⿰山大, is actually usually decomposed as ⿽大〣.
The text itself I have found in this 中日關係史料通商與稅務〈禁運附〉上下：民國元年至五年.

Oh, thank you so much, that is great! I would not have been able to find that by myself!

I almost forgot: Thank you for providing the reference as well! I did not know these documents had been published by the Academia Sinica - that is good to know!
